# Regular Expression symbol "?" not working in shell

Tags: linux

I have one file with the following data. I am using `egrep` as the command 
    which is used for extended regular expression pattern

```
test
best
+see
done++
feett
ttesingt
```

I want the output as below

```
best
+see
done++
vino+
```

I am using the below command for the output

```
egrep 't?' filename.
```

We know that the meaning of `?` is zero or one occurrence of previous 
    character. So in my case `t` is optional if it present it has only one `t` but i 
    am getting all lines as output.

Please let me know how to achieve the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, `egrep 't?' filename` essentially means "find me a 't' character, but if it's absent, that's OK too".

---

Let's start with `egrep 't'`, this asks to find one `t` character. It doesn't say only one character, so it will match "at", "att", "attt" and so on.

Then you add "?" to it -- `egrep 't?'`, making "t" optional, now it matches "a", "at", "att", "abc", "xyz" and basically any other string you can imagine.

In case of one-character searches the "?" modifier doesn't really make any sense, only when there's more to find, like for example `egrep 'ab?c'` that matches "abc", "acd", but not "abb".

---

**How to make your example work?**

A simple way will be just to chain two egreps together:

```
egrep t filename | egrep -v tt
```

First egrep gives you only lines containing at least one `t`, the second one will throw away all lines with two (or more) `t` characters together.

More complex solution using regexp will look like this:

```
egrep '^((^|[^t]+)t($|[^t]+))+$' filename
```

I would personally prefer the first one :)

Comment: thanks for your reply What is difference between t* and t?. I my case both are providing same output

Comment: For single character searches both are meaningless -- "find me zero or one t" and "find me zero or multiple t" will match everything. But if you add some context, you'll see the difference. `at?c` will match "ac" and "atc" only, while `at*c` will match "ac", "atc", "attc", "attt....tttc" and so on. If you remove the "c" character, both `at?` and `at*` will act the same because egrep searches for a _substring_, unless you anchor your search with `^` and `$` (start and end of the line), and "atttt" obviously contains an "at" substring inside itself.

Answer (score 1):

`?` means: The preceding item is optional and matched at most once.

In your question, `egrep 't?' filename` means, you are considering it as optional right.

Meanwhile `egrep '?' filename` (here `t` is zero occurrence), so it will print total file output.

Example : If you give `egrep 'tt?' filename`, it means here first character is `'t'` and next chracter `'t?'` is optional zero occurrence. So the output will be

`egrep 't' filename`

Comment: Thanks for your reply its working. Then may i know what is the difference between 't*' and t? both are equal right

Comment: @iamarunk - Both ? and * are not equal [ example : t* means zero or more occurrence , ? mean matched at least once ]                                                                                           A regular expression may be followed by one of several repetition operators:
       ?      The preceding item is optional and matched at most once.
       *      The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
       +      The preceding item will be matched one or more times.